# Visual Basic: Make 1 button do 2 operations

Tags: vb.net

So I need a button to complete two operations but in two steps. Here is the first buttons code:

First button (button6)

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click

    p = Process.GetProcessesByName("SbieSvc")
    If p.Count > 0 Then
        Environment.Exit(0)
    Else

    End If
    Dim antiProcess() As String = {"SbieSvc", "Sandboxiecrypto", "sbiectrl"}
    For intI As Integer = 0 To antiProcess.GetUpperBound(0)
        For Each x As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName(antiProcess(intI))
            x.Kill()
        Next
    Next
    ''Sets the Channel''
    If TextBox6.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a Channelname!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, ("Error"))
        GoTo Bottom
    End If
    Me.Data = Me.TextBox6.Text
    Me.Method_1(String.Format("Channel set ({0})", Data))
    If (Me.thread0 Is Nothing) Then
        Me.thread0 = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Method2)) With
        {
            .IsBackground = True
        }
        Me.thread0.Start()
    End If
    ''Part Of Grab Urls Method''
    Button6.Enabled = False
    For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox5.Text Step 1
        Dim t1 As New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(Sub() GetUrls(TextBox6.Text)))
        t1.Start()
    Next
    GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
End Sub

  Second button (button1)  

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ''start live viewers''
    Button1.Enabled = False
    For Each itemss In Urls.Items
        Dim t1 As New Threading.Thread(Sub() LivePeepz(itemss))
        t1.Start()
    Next
End Sub
```

How would I make this code so that button6 will complete it's normal commands, then once done it begins button1's operation. I thought about doing this;

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click

    p = Process.GetProcessesByName("SbieSvc")
    If p.Count > 0 Then
        Environment.Exit(0)
    Else

    End If
    Dim antiProcess() As String = {"SbieSvc", "Sandboxiecrypto", "sbiectrl"}
    For intI As Integer = 0 To antiProcess.GetUpperBound(0)
        For Each x As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName(antiProcess(intI))
            x.Kill()
        Next
    Next
    ''Sets the Channel''
    If TextBox6.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a Channelname!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, ("Error"))
        GoTo Bottom
    End If
    Me.Data = Me.TextBox6.Text
    Me.Method_1(String.Format("Channel set ({0})", Data))
    If (Me.thread0 Is Nothing) Then
        Me.thread0 = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Method2)) With
        {
            .IsBackground = True
        }
        Me.thread0.Start()
    End If
    ''Part Of Grab Urls Method''
    Button6.Enabled = False
    For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox5.Text Step 1
        Dim t1 As New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(Sub() GetUrls(TextBox6.Text)))
        t1.Start()
    Next
    GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    ''start live viewers''
    Button1.Enabled = False
    For Each itemss In Urls.Items
        Dim t1 As New Threading.Thread(Sub() LivePeepz(itemss))
        t1.Start()
End Sub
```

But this doesn't work...Any ideas? Thanks. VB2012

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in seperate functions e.g. Function1 would contain the code you intended for first button click. Function2 would have the code intended for second button click.

Then you have one button with an onClick event code that is

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(byVal sender as Object, byVal e as EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Function1()
    Function2()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
FirstOperation()
SecondOperation()
End Sub

Private Sub FirstOperation()
'Button 6 Code
End Sub

Private Sub SecondOperation()
'Button 1 Code
End Sub
```